# uploaded file not storing into directory in yii framework

Tags: php, yii, controller

i done file uploaded concept in Yii framework. data filed's are storing into database but it is not storing into directory folder. i created book folder in home directory

i specified like below mention:

```
  $ResumePath->saveAs(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../images/'.$model->ebook_name=$fileName);
```

directory is 
project name/books/protected.

please tell me how specify the directory.

Comment: Hi this part is for sure wrong $model->ebook_name=$fileName, try just $filename, or $model->ebook_name, your basically setting  $model->ebook_name equal to $fileName and using nothing as the filename.  Single equal sign "=" is the assignment operator....  Even if it was equality "==" that wouldn't work either ( by the way )

Comment: even though i changed here its not working

Comment: $ResumePath=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'ebook_name');
    $fileName="{$id}-{$ResumePath}"; 
                       if (is_object($ResumePath) && get_class($ResumePath)==='CUploadedFile') 
   {
                           $model->ebook_name=$fileName;
                            
                        }
   if($model->save())
                        {
                             if(is_object($ResumePath))
                                 $ResumePath->saveAs(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../images/'.$model->ebook_name=$fileName);

Comment: this way i put it there

Comment: can you add that to the post, hard to read it in the comment section.

Comment: i put it as answer part please suggest me...

Comment: i think /../../books/ thiz could be wrong  instead of /../

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
 $ResumePath=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'ebook_name');
        $fileName="{$id}-{$ResumePath}";  //assuming can be put as a string, its an object? I'm not a Yii guy.
        if (is_object($ResumePath) && get_class($ResumePath)==='CUploadedFile'){
            $model->ebook_name=$fileName;
        }
        if($model->save()){
            if(is_object($ResumePath))
                $ResumePath->saveAs(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../books/'.$fileName);
```

To explain,

```
$ResumePath=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'ebook_name');
$fileName="{$id}-{$ResumePath}";  //here you build the file name,
if (is_object($ResumePath) && get_class($ResumePath)==='CUploadedFile'){
    $model->ebook_name=$fileName; //here you assign it to the $model whatever that is.
}
if($model->save()){
    if(is_object($ResumePath))
        $ResumePath->saveAs(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../books/'.$model->ebook_name=$fileName); //here you again assign it to the model, and output no file name.
```

Then end result of that is a file name basically like this.

```
$ResumePath->saveAs(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../books/'; //no filename.
```

Comment: even those not storing into directory.. what the issue i dont know

Answer (score 0):

```
$ResumePath=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'ebook_name');
$fileName="{$id}-{$ResumePath}"; 
if (is_object($ResumePath) && get_class($ResumePath)==='CUploadedFile'){
    $model->ebook_name=$fileName;
}
if($model->save()){
    if(is_object($ResumePath))
        $ResumePath->saveAs(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../books/'.$model->ebook_name=$fileName);
```

this much only bro... i created folder name books. which is directory itself.

Comment: You have no file name like this.